# Get back unseen shelf changes

Tags: intellij-idea, shelve

I have a problem of shelve changes being lost. I was modyfying the project so much, that the history of shelve changes got exceeded in IntelliJ panel. (panel I mean second picture from: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html)

Now the question is if I can somehow find the shelved changes on local disk, now that they are not shown in the most recent ones in IJ?

I have already checked `{ProjectName}/.idea/shelf` dir. But wasn't there.